# How I fix this? [Access is denied] | Virtual devices in android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, adb, access-denied

I trying to access the console of Android with Command Prompt, but instead to seems emulator device to look "access is denied".

ps. I'm new in Android Development

Already tried to add: adb root, don't fix it

"Estou tentando acessar o console do android pelo Prompt de Comando, no entanto só tenho como retorno o erro de acesso negado (access is denied)"

**Image do prompt**
[image: image do prompt]

**This is my goal**
[image: This is my goal]

Answer (score 0):

I will answer me! To verify I saw *Tools* in IDE > Android > sdk manager and *Android SDK location:* is the real local , i thought is in disk c but not was!

AndroidStudio: https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html

[SDK MANAGER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCU7i.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Here I had the same problem on windows. wiping the data of the AVD worked for me.

Just go to the AVD manager and right click on it. Then wipe the data. Start it from the right hand side run button.

Let it take time and run.
Once it is running then debug the app.

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

The error "Access is denied." occurs if I mistakenly type `>adb -s emulator-5554 shell` (with the extra prefix **>**) instead of `adb -s emulator-5554 shell`. So, double-check your full command if you encounter this issue.

In the OP's case, using the `C:\>` prompt to run the command `android-studio\sdk\platform-tools>adb devices` — which contains the redirection mark `>` as part of the command — is a mistake similar to mine and leads to the same error.